# How to insert @ symbol between name and address

Tags: insert, ssms, symbols

SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Table: Users
Field: EmailAddress

ISSUE: I have an email address field that is missing the @ symbol before the address. 
GOAL: I need a method of inserting the @ symbol for over 100 email addresses.

EXPECTED: gdilbert@website.com
ACTUAL:   gdilbertwebsite.com

The website is the exact same amount of characters for all email addresses.
The name will be different for each email address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this UPDATE Customers SET email = SUBSTRING(email,1,LEN(email)-11)+'@'+'website.com';

So this will remove the website.com from the string and add @website.com.